# Gesture Detectors not working after ImageView.setRotation() call

Tags: java, android, rotation, imageview, gesturedetector

I've faced a problem with rotation of imageview. Here's a code that I use to rotate my imageview.

```
public void rotateImg(float angle) {
    imageView.setRotation(angle);
}
```

After angle becomes >0 gesture detectors stop working. When I set rotation back to 0, detectors start to work again.

Here's a link of gesture detectors implementation https://github.com/Almeros/android-gesture-detectors.

Please help to fix this problem.

Comment: and you really think that anybody will study all of your files?

Comment: I thought maybe somebody had a problen like this and he can help me.

Comment: setRotation has nothing to do with MotionEvents that are used by GestureDetector so you must be doing something wrong

Comment: But when I rotate imageview like this everything works fine          `Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        int pivX = imageView.getDrawable().getBounds().width() / 2;
        int pivY = imageView.getDrawable().getBounds().height() / 2;
        matrix.preRotate(angle, pivX, pivY);
        imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);`

Comment: hmm, are you sure? if so, i withdraw my previous words, sorry for confussion

Comment: That's ok, I was already confused before you told me that)

Comment: ok i probably know whats happening: GestureDetector's methods work the dame but probably you want to transform your target based of them but since the view is rotated when you want to move it for example horizontally it moves with the angle it was rotated

Comment: Probably, but there's no any action. ImageView isn't changing.

Comment: what do you mean? what exact problems do you have with views rotated with setRotation?

Comment: I mean if the GestureDetectors worked as usual then for rotated ImageView must change but not in appropriate way. In my case ImageView stand still and GestureListeners don't execute